# Azure publishsettings file Fails to Import Using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using my MSDN Azure subscription to try to publish a Java web site using Eclipse.  I have installed the Azure SDK v2.6 and the Azure plug-in for Eclipse v0.2.0.201506041823.  As part of the deployment set-up, I need to import my Publish-Settings file.  I have downloaded the publish profile from the Azure portal. When I import the publishsettings file, I am getting this error:
Importing filename file failed.
Reason: Failed to parse file. Ensure publish settings file is valid.

Any idea what I am missing?
I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you open the settings file to make sure it looks valid?

Comment: Yes, I did look at the file. It contains XML tags for publishData and publishProfile. As this is the first one I have seen, I can't be sure what it should look like. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the file you downloaded is Azure subscription publish setting, not the website publish file(yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net.PublishSettings). Your subscription file should be named like this :

```
Your Subscription Name-6-15-2015-credentials.publishsettings
```

Like Jambor said, another method you can download file form eclipse:
[image]

Then, you can input your Azure account and login on Azure portal, then you can download the publishsettings file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile command in powershell to import your publish settings file, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385850(v=nav.70).aspx for more details, if you could get your subscription information, this issue maybe related to your java environment, else, please re-download the publish settings file.

Comment: It would be better if you can share a standard working file's content(remove personal data) and format to Rick to have a furthur comparing.