# Error importing subscriptions from publish settings file (Azure) Eclipse

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I can`t import subscription file (**Azure**) into Eclipse. When I try to do this I get a message:

> "Error importing subscriptions from publish-settings file"

Maybe someone can help me to resolve this issue, I will be grateful.

Comment: No more error details?

Answer (score 0):

There are some similar SO threads & offical document which be helpful for you, please see below.

1. [Azure deployment with eclipse result in error importing subscriptions from publish settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094032/azure-deployment-with-eclipse-result-in-error-importing-subscriptions-from-publi)
2. [Azure publishsettings file Fails to Import Using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805837/azure-publishsettings-file-fails-to-import-using-eclipse)
3. [How to: Download and Import Publish Settings and Subscription Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385850%28v=nav.70%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Please follow these above to try again. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.